# Изменение яркости экрана

Tags: java, android

Как задать определенный процент яркости экрана в приложении? К примеру, 30%.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Добавьте в манифесте AndroidManifest.xml файл строчку с разрешением:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Код для изменения яркости:

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, value);
```

[Пример с сикбаром](http://www.android-examples.com/set-change-screen-brightness-in-android-programmatically/), который меняет яркость экрана.
[enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18312609/change-the-system-brightness-programmatically).

Comment: Но Ваш ответ мне очень помог, спасибо!

Comment: На 10 Андроиде этот способ не работает

Answer (score 3):

Не видит разрешения в манифесте... Странно. 
Помог вот этот код:

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams layout = getWindow().getAttributes();
    layout.screenBrightness = 0.3F;
    getWindow().setAttributes(layout);
```

Минус его в том, что надо вписывать в каждом активити.