# Управление подсветкой в своем приложении

Tags: android, display

Написал приложение, добавил ночной режим, хочу с его включением сбрасывать подсветку дисплея на самый минимум, возможно ли? По гуглу ничего не смог найти, может запросы неправильно составлял.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571007