# Изменение яркости экрана Android

Tags: android, экран

Мне нужно поменять яркость экрана. Делаю это вот так:

```
ContentResolver cResolver = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getContentResolver();
Settings.System.putInt(cResolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, brightness);
```

Но яркость меняется постепенно (как будто затухает). Есть ли способ сразу изменить её на нужное значение?

Comment: Вам нужно именно для всей системы яркость менять? Может такой вариант подойдёт: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/571007/11515 ?

Comment: Спасибо, но хотелось бы именно системную яркость менять.

Comment: Вряд ли можно повлиять на плавность системной настройки. Если не будет решения, то попробуйте меняется ли яркость как надо через параметры окна - если да, то можно соорудить такой костыль: менять яркость окна, а потом системную.